# Defining typedef struct in header, and c file

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm trying to define a new type for something im making, this is the barebones version:

vectors.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD_VECTORS
#define HEADER_GUARD_VECTORS

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    vector2 operator=(vector2 vector);
}
double vector2_get_angle(vector2 vector);
#endif
```

vectors.c

```
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    inline vector2 operator=(vector2 value)
    {
        x = value.x;
        y = value.y;
        return value;
    }
} vector2;

double vector2_get_angle(vector2 vector)
{
    return atan2(vector.y,vector.x) * (180.0 / PI);
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.c>
#include "vectors.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    vector2 vec = {x=1, y=2};
    printf("Vector: %d, %d ",vec.x,vec.y);
    printf(" has an angle of %d degrees\n",vector2_get_angle(vec));
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -lm -lc -lgcc

all: test

test: vectors.o test.o
    gcc test.o vectors.o -o test

test.o: test.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) test.c

vectors.o: vectors.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) vectors.c
```

Make command feedback

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall -lm -lc -lgcc vectors.c
vectors.c:8:2: error expected specifier-qualifier-list before ?inline?
vectors.c:20:33: warning: ?struct vector2? declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
vectors.c:20:33: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
vectors.c:20:41: error: parameter 1 (?vector?) has incomplete type
vectors.c: In function ?vector2_get_angle?:
vectors.c:23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Now my main question:

How do i define the type correctly in the header and the vectors.c source file so that i can use it as shown in test.c.

Thank you for reading my question

Comment: You are using C++ with a C compiler. That will not work. As well as the typedef in the header file is missing.

Comment: What part of the code is C++? also could you be more specific about the missing typedef?

Comment: Operator overloading is a C++-only thing, there is no such thing in C.

Comment: As for the typedef, you have `typedef struct { ... }` directly followed by a function declaration, no semicolon, and more specifically no name for the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

> How do i define the type correctly in the header and the vectors.c source file so that i can use it as shown in test.c.

You have to write it in the correct programming language. Your code is invalid in C, since it does not support operator overloading or any other C++ feature.

Furthermore, the **inline** keyword was introduced in the C99 standard, so you have to compile with `-std=c99`.

Also, `typedef struct {}` needs to end with a type name at the end.

Also, `vector2` is not defined anywhere in scope of the header file.